# ¿Como enlazar React Routes, para utilizarlo dentro de una misma página?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, router

Buenas soy nuevo por acá y también estoy aprendiendo a programar con react, tengo el siguiente problema, dentro de la página home quisiera poner un sub menú en la mitad de la página, al cual al hacer clic a cada uno de los enlaces, debajo me cargue cierta información. Yo lo hice con React Route pero el problema que me surge es que me dibuja una pagina nueva, y yo quiero que lo dibuje en una parte de home. No se si me estoy expresando bien y si se entiendo lo que quiero hacer. Les voy a dejar una foto de lo que quiero lograr y también el código de lo que realice hasta el momento.
***Un comentario no ejecuten el código porque como no se utilizar StackoverFlow no funciona el codigo ahi, solo lo utilice para poder pegar por separado los archivos que tenia.*** Desde ya muchísimas gracias. Saludos Matías.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
//REALICE UN ARRAY DE OBJETOS PARA NO LLENAR TANTO EL COMPONENTE CON LISTAS.

export const dataSubMenu = [
    {
        id: 1, name: "Landing Page", boton:"Comienza Hoy", Link:"landing"
    },
    {
        id: 2, name: "Tienda Web", boton:"Comienza Hoy", Link:"tienda"
    },
    {
        id: 3, name: "Web Empresarial", boton:"Comienza Hoy", Link:"webEmpresarial"
    },
    {
        id: 4, name: "Web Hosting", boton:"Comienza Hoy", Link:"webHosting"
    },
    {
        id: 5, name: "Mas Servicios", boton:"Comienza Hoy", Link:"otrosServicios"
    },
]
```

```css
/* ESTE ES EL COMPONENTE subMenu*/

import { dataSubMenu } from "./dataSubMenu";
import './subMenu.css';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export const SubMenu = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <section className="conteiner__sub__menu">
        <ul>
            
            {dataSubMenu.map((item) => (
                  
                <li key={item.id}>
                <NavLink className='menu__Item--a' to={item.Link} >
                   <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                   </NavLink>
                </li>
                
            ))}
        </ul>
    </section>
    </>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js">

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { Header } from "./components/headers/header";
import { HomePage } from "./routes/home";
import { ProductsPage } from "./routes/products";
import { MasServiciosPage } from "./routes/masServicios";
import { NosotrosPage } from "./routes/nosotros";
import { ContactPage } from "./routes/contact";
import { NotFoundPage } from "./routes/notFoundPage";
import "./app.css";

import { LandingPage } from "./routes/landing";
import { TiendaPage } from "./routes/tienda";
import { WebEmpresarialPage } from "./routes/webEmpresarial";
import { WebHostingPage } from "./routes/webHosting";
import { OtrosServiciosPage } from "./routes/otrosServicios";
export const ThemeContext = createContext(null);

function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");
  let html = document.querySelector("html");
  html.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
      <>
        <Router>
           {/* TODO LO QUE ESTE POR FUERA DE <ROUTES> FUNCIONA COMO LAYOUT */}
          <Header />


          <Routes>
            {/* DEFINIMOS LAS RUTAS QUE VAMOS A USAR EN ROUTES*/}
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<ProductsPage />} />
            <Route path="/masServicios" element={<MasServiciosPage />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
            <Route path="/nosotros" element={<NosotrosPage />} />
           
           {/*ABAJO EMPIEZA EL CODIGO QUE ESCRIBI PARA ESO*/}
            <Route path="/landing" element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route path="/tienda" element={<TiendaPage />} />
            <Route path="/webEmpresarial" element={<WebEmpresarialPage />} />
            <Route path="/webHosting" element={<WebHostingPage />} />
            <Route path="/otrosServicios" element={<OtrosServiciosPage />} />
           
           <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
          </Routes>

          
        </Router>
      </>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
</script>
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, necesitas aplicar composición de componentes para lograr esa estructura, entonces cuando dices que el link te lleva a otra pagina ¿Significa que no vez el menu Productos, mis servicios, nosotros...en esa otra página? ese menu es parte del home supongo

Comment: Hola si el menú como se ve en la imagen 2 se ve, pero ese es el menu principal. Yo lo que quiero es que dentro del la pagina Home poder poner una sub página . Te subo una foto de lo que quiero lograr, pero bueno no iría esa información.  Y me decis si eso se puede lograr con route. Porque la verdad nose si se puede o no. Gracias desde ya

Comment: Ahi subi una foto numero 3 que es lo que quiero armar algo asi, un sub menu y dentro de ese sub menu que me cambie de contenido. Logicamente siempre estando dentro de la pagina Home.

Comment: Parece que estas usando la version 6 de react-router de ser así debiste haber configurado el objeto `createBrowserRoute` compártelo es necesario para emular tu app de mi lado, si puedes cambiar de stack  recomiendo que uses Next.JS y descartes el router v6, nextJS tiene un sistema de rutas mas intuitivo y ademas se puede usar composición con sus archivos layout/pages